# APScheduler running a Python Script

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, apscheduler

I have a python script which is a scraper. I want it to run every 10 minutes. Currently it is in its own docker container and with EntryPoint to a python file.

```
def main():
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(scraper, 'interval', seconds=600)
    scheduler.start()
```

This works fine for about 2 weeks but then stops and I am required to restart the docker container. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Anything in the logs when it crashes ? Not exactly what you are looking for but another option is to set it up to run once and call docker run from host using cron.

Comment: What do you mean by stops? Does the Docker container exit? More info is needed.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm Unfortunately, I don't have more information. Docker container is still running but the scraper never runs. As part of the scraper the first thing it does is write the date to a log file but this isn't done any more. I was thinking of changing it so the python script (without APscheduler) is run as a cron?

Comment: Or try setting up logging properly so you'll see what goes wrong.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm I suppose my question is which is better to do a cron or APscheduler? I've noticed in the logs it comes up as `Execution of job "scraper (trigger: interval[0:10:00], next run at: 2017-01-15 13:45:35 UTC)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)` Currently trying to work out what that means/how to resolve it.

Comment: Is there a command to see a list of all current running instances of apscheduler jobs? I'm guessing the error above means there is more than 1instance so for some reason the last one hasn't ended yet. I'm just not sure how to troublehsoot it.